# highcharter: BoxPlot Outliers not being on correct x-axis point

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Have a data set that I would like to create a box plot graph with outliers in `highcharter`. The boxplot works but I can't seem to get the outliers on the correct `x-axis` position; they all are grouped on position 0 for some reason. The box plots are correct so I am not sure why the outliers don't follow the box plot.

Below is my code:

```
library (highcharter)

Quote <- c(12,15,16,12,14,19,13,12,17,15,14,18,22,25,29,30,14,2,5,4)
Other <- c(30,35,36,12,18,35,39,41,42,43,45,31,37,35,32,31,34,36,32,15)
Shop <- c(2,1,5,4,6,9,5,4,7,8,1,5,4,3,5,4,1,5,15,19)
PN <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Dat <- data.frame(Quote,Other,Shop, PN)

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_boxplot(Dat$Quote, Dat$PN, name = "Quote Hold Time", color = "#FF8888", pointStart = 0) %>%
  hc_add_series_boxplot(Dat$Other, Dat$PN, name = "Other Hold Time", color = "#E5A919", pointStart = 1) %>%
  hc_add_series_boxplot(Dat$Shop, Dat$PN, name = "Shop Time", color = "#51C1BC", pointStart = 2) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Quote Hold","Other Hold","Shop Time"), labels = list(enabled = TRUE)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value} days"), min = 0) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(grouping = FALSE))
```

Below is the picture of the problem. All of the `scatter (outliers)` are positioned under Quote Hold category on the x-axis.

[image]

Comment: Have you add oultliers series as scatter series where each point has both x and y coordinates? **Demo in JS:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gr5m7ykw/

Comment: Hi @KamilKulig, `hc_add_series_boxplot` adds the outliers automatically, I don't add a scatter series myself which is why I am not sure how to format a series I didn't add and that doesn't conform to the boxplot coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out doing some data manipulation so all the data is within one series. I couldn't figure out how to make the outliers the same color as the boxplot in a given x-column but turning them all to the same shade works as well.

```
library (highcharter)

Quote <- c(12,15,16,12,14,19,13,12,17,15,14,18,22,25,29,30,14,2,5,4)
Other <- c(30,35,36,12,18,35,39,41,42,43,45,31,37,35,32,31,34,36,32,15)
Shop <- c(2,1,5,4,6,9,5,4,7,8,1,5,4,3,5,4,1,5,15,19)
PN <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Dat <- data.frame(Quote,Other,Shop, PN)

Dat$QuoteType <- rep("Quote",nrow(Dat))
Dat$OtherType <- rep("Other",nrow(Dat))
Dat$ShopType <- rep("Shop",nrow(Dat))

Dat1 <- Dat[,c("Quote","QuoteType")]
colnames(Dat1) <- c("Value","Type")
Dat2 <- Dat[,c("Other","OtherType")]
colnames(Dat2) <- c("Value","Type")
Dat3 <- Dat[,c("Shop","ShopType")]
colnames(Dat3) <- c("Value","Type")

DatComb <- rbind(Dat1,Dat2,Dat3)

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_boxplot(DatComb$Value, DatComb$Type, colors = c("#FF8888","#E5A919","#51C1BC"), name = "Test") %>%
  hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value} days"), min = 0) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(boxplot = list(colorByPoint = TRUE), scatter = list(color = c("#A6BBC8")))
```